# How can I add an image in all the cells in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c

I am using this in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] imageNamed:@"arrow.jpg"];
  cell.imageView.image = image; 
  return cell;
}
```

cell.imageView.image is throwing error..

Comment: I am declaring cell... It is just part of the code....

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean a runtime error because that code as-is won't compile (because cell is not declared).

This line:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] imageNamed:@"arrow.jpg"];
```

should be:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.jpg"];
```

`imageNamed` is a UIImage class method, not an instance method.

**Edit:**
As you requested, to put the image on the right instead of the left, you can try this:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.jpg"]];
cell.accessoryView = iv;
[iv release];
```

If your cell layout requires more flexibility than what's built in, you'll need to add your own views to cell.contentView or just design a custom cell in IB.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [atable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

 }
 [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];

 NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [cell.textLabel setText:cellValue]; 


 return cell;
}

Comment: [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];

Comment: Now it works.. but image is left aligned i need in right what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach in a game i an developing.

You subclass UITableViewCell, then you add a UIImageView and UILabel to the cell programatically. this gives you a great way to customize the look of your cell.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code
        headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14];
        descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        descriptionLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:11];
        descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        [self.contentView addSubview:headerLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:descriptionLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageV];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
    CGRect frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+60 ,3, 200, 15);
    headerLabel.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+60 ,18, 260, 39);
    descriptionLabel.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+3 , 3, 54, 54);
    imageV.frame = frame;
}
```

Also you will have to change a method in the UITableView class:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    AchievementCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[AchievementCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell returnCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell returnImageAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Feel free to ask any more questions regarding the code :)

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.jpg"];
return cell;

}
```